# Stack overflow for recursive count of elements in java

Tags: java, recursion, count

I'm trying to count the number of Ones in the binary representation of an integer. I need to do this recursively.  I think my logic is correct but I continue to get a stack overflow.  I'm on day 2 troubleshooting.  Here's my code:

```
    static int CountRecursive(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (n >= 0) {
        if (n%2 == 1) {
            sum ++;
        } sum += CountRecursive(n/2);
    } return sum;
}
```

My logic is based on this information:  "The standard mechanism for converting from decimal to binary is to repeatedly divide the decimal number by 2 and, at each division, output the remainder (0 or 1)."

Comment: Note though that you have to tweak your solution even more to work for negative integers too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the equals in the if. 0 divided by 2 is still zero - you go into infinite recursion.

I mean make this one:

`if (n >= 0)`

strict comparison i.e:

`if (n > 0)`